# Deployment Question :: Single Tier vs Multi-Tier

Tags: deployment

Just asked by interviewer deployment between single vs multi-tier? I wasnt sure what he was talking about... Can anyone shed any light on this? Is he talking about following type scenario?

35) What are some common examples of SharePoint 2010 services architectures, and what are the advantages of each design?
The three most popular designs are single farms with either a single service application group or multiple service application groups, or Enterprise services farms.
Single farms with a single service application group are generally the most common, and have the advantages of easy deployment, simple service application allocation, effective resource utilization and cohesive management.
Single farms with multiple service application groups is less common, and have the advantage of potential individual management of service applications as well as allowing data isolation, and while being more complex to deploy and maintain allows targeting of sites to particular service applications.
Enterprise Service Farms is pretty uncommon as it is a complete farm dedicated to Service Applications but promotes autonomous management and high levels of data isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at MS topology examples:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6096

Think of tiers like shelves in a book case, and each shelf can have only one type of server.

So an example single tier:

- 1 Server with all SharePoint roles + SQL

A two-tier

- Web Server
- DB Server

N-Tier

- -Web Servers
- -Application Server
- -Database Servers

I would spend a fair amount of time going over the resources on TechNet, in particular those here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518643.aspx , as this will get you more acquainted with the terminology associated around SharePoint infrastructures.

Comment: I second Jesus' recommendation to read TechNet guidance. There is a Deployment Scenarios Section that goes into detail on installation of a single server and 3 tier server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303424.aspx

Comment: @Jesus: your explanation is in english (not lawyer's language), simple and straight to the point. Thanks